# MySQL removes \ when i want to write file path in java

Tags: java, mysql

I want to get file path from user and set the file path in a data. I can write thre database but the `\` are  missing. Here are the codes;

```
String username = jTextField2.getText();
String password = jTextField3.getText();
String name = jTextField9.getText();
String surname = jTextField10.getText();
boolean male = jRadioButton1.isSelected();
boolean female = jRadioButton2.isSelected();

    try {
        SetNewUserAvatar();
    } catch (IOException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SignUp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

if("".equals(username) || "".equals(password) || "".equals(name) || "".equals(surname)){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please, fill all the gaps");
}
else if( male == false && female == false ){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please, select gender");
}

else {
    DBConnect dbc = new DBConnect();
    try {
        dbc.registerUser(username, password);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SignUp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    try {
        if( male==true ){
        dbc.writeInfo(ProfilePanel.avatarPath[ProfilePanel.xx], name, surname, "male");
        System.out.println(ProfilePanel.avatarPath[ProfilePanel.xx]);
        }
        else{
        dbc.writeInfo(ProfilePanel.avatarPath[ProfilePanel.xx], name, surname, "female");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SignUp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    SignUp.super.dispose();
    }
```

this code is in another class;

```
    public void writeInfo(String avatarpath, String name, String surname, String gender) throws SQLException {
    String query = "select * from info";
    rs = st.executeQuery(query);


    while(rs.next()){
    x = rs.getInt("id");
    }

 st.executeUpdate( "INSERT INTO  info"  + " (id, avatarpath, name, surname, gender) VALUES ('"+(x+1)+"','"+avatarpath+"', '"+name+"', '"+surname+"', '"+gender+"' )");
}
```

When I press the register button, I wanted to see if i am getting the path correctly so the system output is `null
C:\Users\B_Ali\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication20\build\classes\Users\shingeki_no_kyojin_by_asuka10-d6k762k.jpg`

Edit: I get input from this func.

```
public static void SetNewUserAvatar() throws IOException, SQLException{
    DBConnect dbc = new DBConnect();
    dbc.counter();
    ProfilePanel.xx = dbc.x;
    File file = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
    ProfilePanel.avatarPath[ProfilePanel.xx] = file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Comment: Replace with double backslashes before writing? I'd guess that mysql treats these as escape characters.

Comment: What is your current output (and from where...MySQL or Java), and what output do you want?

Comment: By the way, this code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Firstly, stop constructing SQL like that. It's a *terrible* way of providing values to SQL. Learn about parameterised SQL and prepared statements... you may find the problem goes away at that point anyway, and your code will *certainly* be in a better state afterwards (and one which is less vulnerable to SQL injection attacks).

Comment: You need to use prepared statements. Otherwise you are vulnerable to SQL injections, backslashes being ignored and other annoyances.

Comment: And also, try using an auto increment field instead of counting all of the existing ids and adding 1.

Comment: I am pretty new for java and SQL. I don't want to use double backslashes because I am getting data from user so, it should be automatic. If I can manage to do this I will go on to learn how to use prepared statements.

Comment: This is how it looks in SQL [link](http://prntscr.com/7s1yeg).

Comment: Replace all the backslashes with double backslashes before you execute the query then. Also, sanitize the inputs.

Comment: Use prepared statements, as you were already been told many times. Googling for "Java prepared statements tutorial" leads to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok I used prepared statement for inserting data. It works now and working code is below. I share it because someone can need it.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
String username = jTextField2.getText();
String password = jTextField3.getText();
String name = jTextField9.getText();
String surname = jTextField10.getText();
boolean male = jRadioButton1.isSelected();
boolean female = jRadioButton2.isSelected();
Connection connection = null ;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    try {
        SetNewUserAvatar();
    } catch (IOException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SignUp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
if("".equals(username) || "".equals(password) || "".equals(name) || "".equals(surname)){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please, fill all the gaps");
}
else if( male == false && female == false ){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please, select gender");
}
else {
     try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");

}catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Error: "  +ex);
}
    DBConnect dbc = new DBConnect();
    try {
        dbc.registerUser(username, password);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SignUp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        if( male==true ){
        DBConnect.addInfo(connection, preparedStatement, ProfilePanel.avatarPath[ProfilePanel.xx], name, surname, "male");
        }
        else{
        DBConnect.addInfo(connection, preparedStatement, ProfilePanel.avatarPath[ProfilePanel.xx], name, surname, "female");;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SignUp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }   
    SignUp.super.dispose();
    }
}
```

This code in another class.

```
 DBConnect(){
  try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");
st = con.createStatement();

Connection connection = null ;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

}catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Error: "  +ex);
}
}
public static void addInfo(Connection connection,PreparedStatement preparedStatement, String avatarPath, String name, String surname, String gender) throws SQLException{
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO info (avatarpath, name, surname, gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
preparedStatement.setString(1, avatarPath);
preparedStatement.setString(2, name);
preparedStatement.setString(3, surname);
preparedStatement.setString(4, gender);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```